# How to get value of any shell set variables in jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

`echo sh(returnstdout true script 'set')`   returns

```
[Pipeline] echo
BASH=/usr/bin/sh
BASHOPTS=cmdhist:extquote:force_fignore:hostcomplete:interactive_comments:progcomp:promptvars:sourcepath
BASH_ALIASES=()
BASH_ARGC=()
BASH_ARGV=()
BASH_CMDS=()
BASH_LINENO=([0]="0")
BASH_SOURCE=([0]=/home/jenkins_slave/xxxxxx/workspace/sachin-dockerDel@tmp/durable-7dca863e/script.sh)
BASH_VERSINFO=([0]="4" [1]="2" [2]="46" [3]="2" [4]="release" [5]="x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu")
BASH_VERSION='4.2.46(2)-release'
BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME='#48'
BUILD_ID=48
BUILD_NUMBER=48
BUILD_TAG=jenkins-sachin-dockerDel-48
BUILD_URL=https://xxxxxxx/job/sachin-dockerDel/48/
CI=true
DIRSTACK=()
EUID=1003
EXECUTOR_NUMBER=1
GROUPS=()
HOME=/home/jenkins_slave
HOSTNAME=dev-compile-004
HOSTTYPE=x86_64
HUDSON_COOKIE=0b74e7c1-d3f0-433f-837f-a3d0d1a3fc5d
HUDSON_HOME=/var/jenkins_home
HUDSON_SERVER_COOKIE=584c96ce34d28299
PWD=/var/xx/xx/sdds/xsdsd/x
.
.
.
```

How to get the values of these params in Jenkinsfile ? want to used few params `HUDSON_COOKIE`
`"echo ${env.HUDSON_COOKIE}"` throws an error `not found`
`"echo ${env.PWD}"` return `blank` 
In short cannot use all the variables as  `env.<variable Name>`

Observed same with `printenv` .
cannot used all the variables as  `env.<variable Name>`. YES some environment variable works like this.

new to Jenkinsfile kindly help to collect value of any variable

Comment: Have you tried echo sh.env.HUDSON_COOKIE ?

Comment: @Sagar Thanks a lot for your reply ```+ sh.env.HUDSON_COOKIE
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/sachin-sh@tmp/durable-88079a94/script.sh: 1: sh.env.HUDSON_COOKIE: not found```  whereas ```  echo sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'set')```
  returns ```HUDSON_COOKIE='da64baac-ad5d-461a-af1d-537d177711d0'```

Comment: Have you tried using ${HUDSON_COOKIE} with the `env.` ?

Comment: @Sagar yes ```${HUDSON_COOKIE}  and ${env.HUDSON_COOKIE}  ``` this is thing i tried

Comment: Can you post your entire Jenkinsfile/pipeline definition in your question, please?

Comment: now manage the is little complicated way that is , collect all these env params in Array